# Query BCS Connection to Update a SP 2013 Library

Tags: document-library, bcs, external-content-type, external-list, external-data

I have a requirement to update a SP 2013 Library (let's call this **Test Library**)

The requirements are detailed below:

- Update all items with a Status = Created
- If Status = Created update: Name, Manager, Dept, etc.

There is a SQL table that stores all the information that I need (let's call this **Employee_Table_DB**).

I was initially thinking of using a BCS connection by creating an External List and using an External Content Type.

However, I was told that using BCS to update the SP Library would not work because there is not a way to write logic against the BCS connection and then update the **Test Library**.

Is this true? I initially thought that I ***COULD*** write against the BCS connection to update a Library.

Can anyone confirm this? If this cannot be done can someone point me in the right direction with performance in mind?